# How to search for literal asterisk in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I have a specific string which I need to search for in in onenote 2013.
The problem is that the string contains several asterisk *** characters. By default, OneNote treats * as a wildcard in searches, so I get thousands of notes returned instead of the few I was expecting.

How do I search for literal wildcards?

Comment: The term typically used for making an exception for an otherwise special character in other programs is Escaping the character.  I haven't found a working way to do this in OneNote though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry - but this is not possible.

Stupid, I know - but after much googling, asking on TechNet, testing various character combinations such as:

- `*
- "*"
- '*'
- *
- \ *
- '#*
  ...and so on
  (known as character escapes)

I have also been unable to find a method for doing this.

This article seems to suggest that it is not possible:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotetips/2010/11/16/searching-for-notes-in-onenote/

> Due to a limitation of Windows Desktop Search, OneNote cannot support substring searches or wildcard searches.

(Unfortunately, this seems to extend to the literal string of wildcard characters too)

Comment: No the answer I was looking for, and hopefully one day a better answer arrives. Until then you get the 'tick', and I have to trawl thousands of notes replacing ***** with a searchable sequence

Comment: @GregWoods The answer is maybe not good news (for you and for all OneNote users), but it's a perfect answer to the question, the way it was asked according to Stack Overflow criteria ;-) Note that other characters have the same issue, e.g. `+` (although it's not your question, but Stack Overflow encourages to generalize the questions)

Comment: This seems to extend to other characters like '>' or '=', it looks like it only wants to search for alphanumeric text

Answer (score 3):

The [OneTastic add-in](https://getonetastic.com/) has turnkey macros like "Search & Highlight" or "Search & Replace" that are able to do this ([link to "Find" category](https://getonetastic.com/macroland&category=Find))

Warning: The Search & Highlight macro will actually highlight all results. If that's not what you're looking for, you can use Search & Replace → replace the wildcard with an unused word, then use standard/native Search to tab through those words. When done, use the Search & Replace to replace the word back to the wildcard character.

Comment: This is a great recommendation.  However, in my case it didn't help because I wanted to include a superscript character in my replace string, but that wasn't possible.  Thanks though!