# how to search embedded excel data in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, microsoft-onenote-2016

I spent lots of time to search on Google, but I couldn't find further interpretation about it.

The historical background is I embedded the Excel sheet to record the specific document name and numbering as a management method.

The advantage is I could see this information between different devices, and the Excel sheet could help me more quickly to numbering. The main issue I face is as picture below:

- I search "M20" with quotes, and some data in the sheet could be found, however, some data couldn't, why?

[image]

- I search "70" with quotes, and there is nothing could be searched, why?

[image]

- I search "VBA" with quotes, and it could be searched.

[image]

- I search Chinese words "解決" with quotes, and nothing could be found on the Excel sheet, but searching can find the words in the OneNote paragraph, why?

[image]

I am really curious about the principle for OneNote to handle the searching method with the embedded Excel sheet. If any person meets somehow similar issues?

Thank you all in advance. I would appreciate any comments on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OneNote is not actually searching the spreadsheet, but searching the image of the spreadsheet. When you right-click the displayed image, you have this option to make the text in the image searchable:

[image]

So, I'm able to find any of the following search terms:

> M c h V P J o w h c

I'm not able to find Chinese characters in that image because the optical character recognition is not able to search for that.

It can find the Chinese characters if they are not in the Excel spreadsheet.

Regarding why it can't find "70", I learned on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1090370/how-to-search-for-literal-asterisk-in-onenote) that OneNote cannot perform substring searches with wildcards of any kind. So, unless the word *begins* with 70, it won't find it.

That post references [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/onenotetips/searching-for-notes-in-onenote). Specifically:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. The goal I would like to do is to create a data searching center by OneNote searching engine, so if one day, I just could only remember one keyword, I could search it whatever the string is in OneNote or embedded excel sheet. but I think there is a big gap in the ideal gaol.